# submitting form on one page urlencodes get values, doesn't on another page

Tags: php, url, character-encoding

I'm trying to sort out an issue with foreign characters and matching those to a database value.

I've managed to get a match out of the database query as I wanted but now I've run into a different problem and simply don't know why what's happening is happening.

On all pages throughout the site there is a header include which has a input field to search the site.
`<form action="/search.php" method="get"><input name="q" type="text" />etc...`

My problem query string was this **grønhøj**. When I enter this string into the input form on the homepage I get taken to the search page with the url like so: **search.php?q=gr%F8nh%F8j** which doesn't work at the moment.
However if I then re-enter that same search query into the header input when im on the search page the page reloads except the url now looks like this: **search.php?q=grønhøj** which does work.

If the resulting url would remain the same all the time, then I'd not have a problem, but because its inconsistent I don't know how to provide solutions to both possible versions of the query string.

So I guess I have 2 questions.

1) Why does the url not stay the same when it's using the exact same form to submit the string?
2) how can I manipulate both versions (or stop the different pages resulting in different urls) of the url so that the resulting string is consistent regardless of which version of the url I get?

**UPDATE:** I found a function to detect utf8 encoding [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php#68607) which allowed me to switch how I handle the url string depending on which version of the url I get, so now my main issue is fixed.

I would still however like to understand why I get the 2 different url variables from the different pages even though the form is a consistent include across the site. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can solve this issue, is to always decode the query string using `urldecode()` and then forcefully use `urlencode()` on it again. This way, if the initial query string was url encoded or decoded, no matter what, it will go through decoding and encoding process again, which will result in the same final query string.

Manual - [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Manual - [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: While in theory that makes sense, in my case it didn't work. I think it was because the already urlencoded string was as is, the not urlencoded one was utf8 encoded, so when urldecode/encode was applied, the resulting string had 2 %## codes for each ø instead of just the one in my first example url. I found a function to detect utf8 encoding which allows me to switch how I maniupulate the string which works.

Comment: right, if you can detect utf-8 (or any other charset encoding), then you are pretty much good to go. it solves ur problem. As an extension to that, you may try to decode and encode again just to make sure you are getting back a pure urlencoded query string. But only if its necessary. If decoding charset solves ur problem, then leave it at that.

Comment: Yep it seems to be fixed now, but your suggestion did help me find out that one was utf8 encoded and the other wasn't so I'll accept your answer for that, Cheers.

Comment: sweet! glad i could help. Good luck!